# Is it possible to send a lot of embeds using one bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm new a this :) this is the first code can't I add more?
I'm using discord.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxbz9.png)

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste your code in your question instead of attaching an image, and provide more details as to what you are wanting to do. In addition, you should keep in mind StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service, and you should attempt at writing the code yourself first. Refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: If I'm correct bots are limited to 1 embed per message. Webhooks on the other hand can send up to 10

Comment: Elitezen you are correct. They can create a webhook, the send embeds with the `embeds` property in the send options filled in

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. But if sending the embed multiple times is what you want you could put the channel.send(exampleEmbed) inside a for loop

Comment: @Ziad_BKL keep in mind methods like these could fall under API Abuse